# AG-Grid update agSelectCellEditor values after grid creation

Tags: javascript, html, ag-grid

I have an array which can change. **I want to update the values for the `agSelectCellEditor` editor, based off this array, after the grid is created**.

The `agSelectCellEditor` editor is a built in ag grid component which allows the use of a dropdown select for updating cell values. https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/provided-cell-editors/#select-cell-editor

For the sake of the question, I have an example program:
There is a list of sports which the user update manually after the grid is created. I am using an ag-grid table. Each entry has an `AthleteName` field and a `sport` field, which represents the sport they play. The user selects the sport from a select drop-down using `agSelectCellEditor`. How can I update the values of the select after the grid is created?

In the example below, the user need to add Tennis as a sport in the list of sports using the `sportListInput`. They change the value of `sportListInput` to Football, Tennis. They then need to select Tennis in Nadal's entry under the 'sport' field using the dropdown provided. **How can I update the values of this select `agSelectCellEditor` as the value of `sportListInput` changes? When I pass a function under values it doesn't work.**

*(By the way - you might need to copy the code and test it since it wouldn't show the grid in the stackoverflow snippet for me)*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--Import ag grid-->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.min.noStyle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="sportListInput" value="Football" placeholder="Separate sports with a comma"></input>
        <button onclick="init();this.setAttribute('style','display:none')">Load Athletes</button>
        <div id="gridDiv" class="ag-theme-alpine" style="height: 500px;"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function init(){
                const data =[
                    {
                        AthleteName: "Rafael Nadal",
                        sport: "Football" //this data is wrong and the user wants to update, but they need to add tennis as a sport in the select editor
                    },
                    {
                        AthleteName: "Cristiano Ronaldo",
                        sport: "Football"
                    }
                ];

                const columnDefs = [
                    {
                        field: "AthleteName",
                    },
                    {
                        field: "sport",
                        cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
                        cellEditorPopup: true,
                        cellEditorParams: {
                            values: getSportList(),//THIS IS WHERE THE agSelectCellEditor IS DEFINED AND ITS VALUES, PASSING A FUNCTION TO UPDATE THE VALUES DOESN'T WORK
                        }
                    }
                ];
                const gridDiv = document.getElementById("gridDiv");
                const gridOptions = {
                    columnDefs: columnDefs,
                    defaultColDef: {sortable: true, filter: true, editable: true},
                };
                new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
            
                gridOptions.api.setRowData(data);
                gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
                console.log(gridOptions)
            };

            function getSportList(){ //returns the list of sports inputted by the user
                const sportListInput = document.getElementById("sportListInput");
                return sportListInput.value.split(",").map(sport => sport.trim());
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your `cellEditorParams` to function definition it works as expected:

```
cellEditorParams: function () { return { values: getSportList() } }

// Or this for more concise/modern way:

cellEditorParams: () => ({ values: getSportList() })
```